# SQL Query -> turn fraction (sting) into decimal

Tags: php, mysql

In my database, I have `odds` stored as fractions (varchar) but I need to convert them to decimals, so I can use later the following statement

```
select Date, Horse, Racetime, min(odds) from horsesrp where odds < 2.5 and odds != 0 and Date >= "2014-12-01" AND Date <= "2014-12-30"  group by racetime
```

Is it possible to convert the `odds` from a fraction e.g. `2/1` into a decimal e.g. `2.0` or I have to write a script for the conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to split the fraction and then simply divide like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX (odds,'/',1),DECIMAL(10,2))/CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(odds,'/',-1),DECIMAL(10,2)) FROM horserp;
```

Answer (score 0):

> DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
>
> Converts a value to DECIMAL data type. The optional arguments M and D
>   specify the precision (M specifies the total number of digits) and the
>   scale (D specifies the number of digits after the decimal point) of
>   the decimal value. The default precision is two digits after the
>   decimal point.

try somethin like:

```
select Date, Horse, Racetime, min(CAST(REPLACE(odds, '/', '.') AS DECIMAL(10,6))) from horsesrp where CAST(REPLACE(odds, '/', '.') AS DECIMAL(10,6)) < 2.5 and odds != '0' and Date >= "2014-12-01" AND Date <= "2014-12-30"  group by racetime
```

But be aware that this is performing slower than converting everything to a decimal with a script

Comment: I'm not sure that this will have the desired result if `odds` contains a string like `'3/2'`

Comment: However, that replace will convert `'3/2'` to `3.2` when it should be `1.5` (`3` divided by `2`)

Comment: ohh i see, i got it wrong, thought he just had the / as a decimal separator :-(